# Seaborn histplot uses weird y axis limits?

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I'm iterating through all columns of my df to plot their densities to see if and how I need to transform/normalize my data. I'm using Seaborn and this code:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=n_rows, ncols=n_cols, figsize=(16,40))
fig.tight_layout() #othwerwise the plots overlapped each other and I couldn't see the column names

for i, column in enumerate(df.columns):
    sns.histplot(df[column],ax=axes[i//n_cols,i%n_cols], kde=True, legend=True, fmt='g')
```

This results in a mostly okay graph, however the scaling of the y axis is waaay too big in some cases:

[image]

City 3 and 4 are just fine, however, the highest `Count` for City 4 is at around 200, yet the plot scales y until 10 000, which makes the data hard to interpret. The x axis also goes way beyond where it should, as the highest cost is at about 1000000, but the plot goes until 25000000. When I plot `City 4` separately and force a `ylim` of 200 and `xlim` of 1000000 I get a much more understandable plot:

[image]

Why is the y axis (and actually, the x axis also) scaled so weirdly, and how can I change my code to scale it down so that I don't get a `ylim` much higher than the actually displayed data?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Set the `shared_yaxis` to `False`.

This will get the subplots to plot at the respective maximum points of the corresponding data.

Example:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=n_rows, ncols=n_cols, figsize=(16,40), sharey=False)
```

Comment: I changed my code to `fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=n_rows, ncols=n_cols, figsize=(16,40), sharey=False, sharex=False)` which didn't have any impact at all... What am I missing here?

Comment: Providing the query with sample data would be helpful to recreate the issue. The solution will be easier to provide then.